# Ambiguity in method invocation..Jboss 6.4 throws IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch error

Tags: ejb-3.0, overloading, jboss6.x

We have recently migrated to Jboss EAP 6.4 from Jboss 4.2. In one of our EJB classes we are having over loaded methods create(AbstractBean) and create(AbstractEntity). The class AbstractEntity is extending AbstractBean class. When we try to invoke the create(AbstractBean) method in Jboss 6.4 instance we are getting  the IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch error, but we are not getting this exception in Jboss 4.2.

When we comment out the create(AbstractEntity) method, the exception is not occurring, also when we try to invoke the method using reflection the exception is not occurring.

But we just wanted to know is there anything to be done in the server configuration to resolve this issue or as mentioned above using reflection is a correct solution.

Can anyone help us understand the Jboss6.4 behavior correctly.

Comment: Does anyone knows about it..please help us.

Answer (score 0):

We were having two methods in a class which having different arugment type but argument type of one method extends argument type of other so JBoss ended up with ambiguity error. we have removed the method with derived class as argument and kept the super class one. That resolved the issue for us.